# Alternative to conv2 in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am playing around with Matlab and trying a variety of different things and finding out ways around achieving things without using built in functions. 
Apparently Matlab  (according to google and their website)   don't  release sourcecode for the "conv2" function . .

Is there an alternative function to "conv2(h1, h2, A)" or a way of coding your own version of it without using Matlabs `conv2` .

The `help` option/keyword in Matlab hasn't really helped me

----edit----

This is code which is an alternative to `conv2(A,B)`. But i'm looking for something similar that deals with `conv2(h1,h2,A)`

```
    function B = convolve(A, k);
    [r c] = size(A);
    [m n] = size(k);
    h = rot90(k, 2);
    center = floor((size(h)+1)/2);
    left = center(2) - 1;
    right = n - center(2);
    top = center(1) - 1;
    bottom = m - center(1);
    Rep = zeros(r + top + bottom, c + left + right);
    for x = 1 + top : r + top
        for y = 1 + left : c + left
            Rep(x,y) = A(x - top, y - left);
        end
    end
    B = zeros(r , c);
    for x = 1 : r
        for y = 1 : c
            for i = 1 : m
                for j = 1 : n
                    q = x - 1;
                    w = y -1;
                    B(x, y) = B(x, y) + (Rep(i + q, j + w) * h(i, j));
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question here - what would you consider a "cool way"? Anyway, the reason the code isn't available is that it has been compiled so that it'll run much faster. If you are interested in the source, have a look at the convolution function in the open-source Ocave.  As an aside, the existence of the built-in functions is kind of the reason why you'd use Matlab in the first place; if you prefer to write everything yourself you may be better served working in C++ (or Java or Python).

Comment: Well I'm self learning and I don't see much learning being achieved by relying on built-in functions. I'm just curious to see if others have got around using built in functions. At this stage speed isn't an issue.

Comment: Fair enough. Anyway, it's still difficult to see what you really want as an answer - a way to do convolution that doesn't use `conv2`? What would make an answer "cool"?

Comment: Haha yes. Please excuse my terminology. That would qualify as cool yes.

Comment: understand what `conv2` does and work up your own algorithm.  you're not learning that much by asking on SO for teh codes either.

Comment: What kind of edit was that (just _removed_ the code formatting) ... and why did "Community" took ownership of such a useless edit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas to do convolution without `conv2`

- Use `im2col` to transform the sliding windows into columns, then perform the convolution in parallel on each column.
- Use the Fourier transform: `ifft(fft(A).*fft(B))` - you'll have to pad the kernel before.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with Jonas, but I'll refer you to another option from the FEX: [`Fast 2-D convolution`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22619-fast-2-d-convolution) is a 2D conv that uses `svd` in order to make it faster under some conditions (you'll need to dig that out of the code).